# how to update item in tablelayout after row selected?

Tags: android, tablelayout, tablerow

I have `TableLayout` with 2 buttons and some textView
I added rows dynamically from sq-lite with these codes and it works:

```
   TableLayout tbl
           = (TableLayout) Vfood.findViewById(R.id.frag_food);
    ///
    ///somecode
    ///
    dbfood.open();
    Cursor cursor = dbfood.getGroupFood(group_Name);
    int i = 1;
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
        TableRow tr = new TableRow(getActivity());
        tr.setId(i);

        //btnAdd
        final Button btnAddDeser = new Button(getActivity());
        btnAddDeser.setText("add");
        btnAddDeser.setId(i);
        TableRow.LayoutParams trParams1 
    = new TableRow.LayoutParams(65, TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        btnAddDeser.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
        btnAddDeser.setTextSize(10);
        btnAddDeser.setPadding(30, 10, 10, 10);
        btnAddDeser.setMaxWidth(65);
        btnAddDeser.setMinimumWidth(70);
            //my problem>
            btnAddDeser.setOnClickListener(mListener);
            //
        tr.addView(btnAddDeser, trParams1);

            // Count
        final TextView trCount = new TextView(getActivity());
        trCount.setText(cursor .getString(3));
        trCountDeserc.setId(i);
        trCount.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        trCount.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
        trCount.setTextSize(10);
        trCount.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 15);
        trCount.setClickable(true);
        tr.addView(trCount);
    ///
    ///other text View
    ///some code

    tbl.addView(tr, 
    new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

       i++;

       } while (cdeser.moveToNext());

         }
     dbDeser.close();                
    return Vfood;
```

}

```
    private OnClickListener mListener = new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

                 //
         //I dont know what shoud i do !
                 //

        }
    };
```

I just want to increase trCount one digit when user click on button.

can anyone help me?

I am new to android.

thanks

Comment: Implement button `click listener`

Comment: try to add `listener` inside loop and get Text from `TextView` using `trCount.getText()` and convert it into `Integer` and then increase it by one

Comment: I am new to android. help me with code please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just add this `Button` click event in your loop

```
 btnAddDeser.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String str=trCount.getText().toString();

           Toast.makeText(getActivity(), str, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
      });
```

Comment: Thank you! My problem Solved! 
I thought I would be hard!